# Question about static member variables

Tags: java, static, static-members

In the following code, it is my assumption that the member variable `mBar` will only be instantiated upon the first construction of a `Foo` object... and that this `mBar` instantiation will be shared with all future `Foo` objects, but the `Bar()` constructor will not be called again. Is this accurate?

```
public class Foo {
  private static Bar mBar = new Bar();

  public Foo() {

  }
```

Comment: Does your hypothesis match what you observed when you tried it?

Comment: The mBar instantiation is indeed shared with all Foo objects, but I am unsure whether or not the Bar constructor is called upon each Foo construction.

Comment: Given the above example, Bar() will only be invoked once regardless of how many times Foo objects are instantiated.  It's not necessarily true that the Bar() constructor won't be called again.  It wouldn't be called again by this class (given how the class is written) because the static member variable has already been constructed.  But there's nothing that prevents other classes, methods, etc. from instantiating another Bar object and thereby invoking the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object might actually be constructed WAY before creation of first Foo.. It will be executed when Classloader loads the Foo.class in memory and this can happen pretty much at any time.... Specifically when you load other classes that use Foo class, or when you call a static method of the class....

Answer (score 4):

Almost, it will get instantiated when the **class** Foo is first loaded. So if you call Foo.mBar (if it were public) you would get the bar instance, even though no instances of Foo have been instantiated.

Answer (score -1):

Your assumptions are mostly accurate.  mBar only gets initialized once for all instances of the class (in the same process).  Note that that doesn't stop any other classes from calling the Bar constructor...

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, it won't necessarily be upon the first construction of a Foo object; it's the first executing reference to a Foo object that will cause the classloader to initialize the static members (thereby calling Bar()).

Comment: Not really.. It will be executed most likely before first Foo object creation.