# When the object gets created

Tags: java

I have below scenario in java.

```
class Apple {

    static Apple ap = new Apple();

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
    }
}
```

When does this global object get created?
If it gets created at the classloader time, does it loads all the non static members at that time?

Comment: There are no non-static members in your example...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about static member variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541805/question-about-static-member-variables)

Comment: *What the compiler actually does is to internally produce a single class initialization routine that combines all the static variable initializers and all of the static initializer blocks of code, in the order that they appear in the class declaration.  This single initialization procedure is run automatically, one time only, when the class is first loaded*  by David Flanagan, author of Java in a Nutshell,

Comment: it **does not** loads non static members at that time

Comment: does the object get created

Answer (score 0):

`ap` gets initialized when the class is first loaded into memory.

When `ap` gets initialized, it creates an `Apple` object and all non-static members of the `ap` object are initialized as specified in the constructor.

So non-static members of `ap` are initialized at class loading time.